# Merge two Strings in java with overlap and with allowed difference

Tags: java, string

I want to 'Merge' two Strings, see the code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printAllPossibleMergedString("abcdefdefd", "defdefdefghi");
    }

    public static void printAllPossibleMergedString(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a + b);
        int maxOverlap = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxOverlap; i++) {
            if (b.startsWith(a.substring(a.length() - i, a.length()))) {
                System.out.println(a + b.substring(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
abcdefdefddefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefghi
```

Now I want to this method become '***Fault Tolerance***' (wish you can understand), something like this:

```
void printAllPossibleMergedString(String a, String b, int tolerance);
```

So if I do:

```
// 'x' means a wrong character
printAllPossibleMergedString("abcdefdefx", "defdefdefghi", 1);
```

will output:

```
abcdefdefxdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefghi
```

while:

```
printAllPossibleMergedString("abcdefdefxx", "defdefdefghi", 1);
```

only output:

```
abcdefdefxxdefdefdefghi
```

and of course:

```
printAllPossibleMergedString("abcdefdefxx", "defdefdefghi", 2);
```

will output:

```
abcdefdefxdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefdefghi
abcdefdefdefghi
```

So how to implement this efficiently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what "Fault Tolerance" is, but a formal way of processing this would be as follows:

For all possibilities on comparing two strings, you can implement something called *Edit Distance* (or at least a variant of it).  Vary the weights of the different operations (eg. insertion at beg/end costs= 1, substitution at beg/end costs= 2), and everything else has infinite costs.  Then generate all possibilities with non-infinite costs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Answer (score 0):

Even if that is not the whole solution to your point, this is a good starting point:

```
public static String mergeStrings(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty()) {
        return s1 + s2;
    }

    if (s1.equals(s2)) {
        return s1;
    }


    int i = 0;
    String sub = s1.substring(i);
    while (i < s1.length()) {

        if (s2.startsWith(sub)) {
            return s1 + s2.replace(sub,  "");
        }

        i++;

        sub = s1.substring(i);
    }

    return s1 + s2;
}
```

No go ahead to calculate the Levenshtein distance for the if clause:

```
if (s2.length() > sub.length() && s2.substring(0, sub.length).levenshtein(sub) < tolerance)
```